# New Pi 400 Won't Boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, eeprom

I’ve received the Pi 400 yesterday and was unable to boot properly.

These are the items I’m using to test the device.

- I have the official RPi HDMI to Micro HDMI cable
- The official RPi power adapter
- The official RPi SD card (32GB)

It is important to note that the monitor does detect a signal of sorts when the device is powered on.
These were my steps in an attempt to boot it, all proving unsuccessful.

- Powered the device without an SD card to see if it works --- I get 3 lights and then a quick 4th followed by going dark.
- Got an SD with the OS from the Pi Imager tool after formatting the card to FAT and FAT32 (Two attempts) --- Solid green light, no image or anything.
- Imaged the SD card with the eeprom from Pi Imager --- I get 3 lights and then a quick 4th followed by going dark.
- Imaged with older eeproms from sources online --- No lights at all.
- I’ve also used another Pi400 with another SD card and it works great, same SD card in mine and it didn’t work at all.

Not sure what else there is to do, can you please help troubleshoot?

Comment: all of the above on the same monitor?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, two different monitors. The other one that worked for my friend with the Pi did not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have tested all elements and all work in a different configuration, only the new pi 400 fails all the time, my logic would say the new pi 400 is faulty and you should get back to the dealer

Comment: Yes, I believe that might be the case unfortunately, thank you!